# Lambda Actions or AggressiveInlining to avoid evaluating and passing complex strings to separate static class?

Tags: c#, function, inline

I'm trying to avoid evaluating and passing strings to a separate static class, if flags set in that class would skip using the strings anyway. Doing basic perf measurements with `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`.  A C# .NET Framework 4.8 library that's a plugin for a speech recognition app.

The plugin makes many calls to a static class, passing various evaluated strings.  Different calls are filtered based on static states set in that class, so the strings are only used if a matching static bool is true. For example

`Logger.MenuWrite(string msg)` will only log the string if `Logger.MenuItems` is true.

From the Stopwatch measurements I think the strings are always getting evaluated regardless of whether the Logger class will not be using them (that is, I don't think JIT isn't inlining). Though the perf hit of this is slight, I'm trying to get every millisecond I can as I scale this up.

What I've tried and test so far:

I added Stopwatch measurements around some loops that made a lot of `Logger.MenuWrite()` calls while `Logger.MenuItems` was false, then measured the same loop with the check for Logger.MenuItems done inline for each call, and saw a definite, repeatable difference - about a millisecond less per 1000 calls with strings that had only a single evaluated field.

I first tried `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]` on the static methods in the Logger class like so:

```
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static void MenuWrite(string msg)
        {
            if (s_MenuItems )
            {   vaProxy.WriteToLog(s_Prefix + msg); }
        }
```

This cut the time for the loop in half, but that is still about 1/2 a millisecond more than if I have an actual direct check in the loop, like:

`if (Logger.MenuItems) { Logger.MenuWrite(msg); }`

So I tried using Delegates, like so:

```
        static Action<string> LogIfMenu = (msg) =>
        {
            if (Logger.MenuItems) { Logger.MenuWrite(msg); }
        };
```

But using `LogIfMenu` call seemed to have the same or worse performance than using `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]`.

Any thoughts on what's causing the perf hit - string evaluation/creation, method calls, something else?  Would appreciate any advice or options, beyond inlining all the calls by hand.  Thanks.

EDITS:

- By evaluating strings, I mean pulling in other data like: `$"Passed: {Cmd.Observable} and {Cmd.Dist}"`
- I'll try to look through the other perf tools listed, but do need to measure time elapsed in the release build
- Afraid I have to use a dynamic object for logging since that's what the app my plugin is with provides.  That said, I don't believe it's part of this issue, so removed it from the code snippet.

EDIT: Modified small reproducible example to be console app.

```
// File1.cs
namespace CS_Console_Test_05
{
    static public class Logger
    {
        public static bool MenuItems = false;
        public static void MenuWrite(string msg)
        {
            if (MenuItems) { Console.WriteLine(msg); }
        }
    }
}

// File2.cs
namespace CS_Console_Test_05
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void LoopMessagesInline()
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                if (Logger.MenuItems)
                { Logger.MenuWrite($"Counting Down to the time {sw.Elapsed}"); }
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Inline Elapsed = {sw.Elapsed}");
        }

        public static void LoopMessagesCall()
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                Logger.MenuWrite($"Counting Down to the time {sw.Elapsed}");
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Called Elapsed = {sw.Elapsed}");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Value for MenuItems:");
                string miRead = Console.ReadLine();
                Logger.MenuItems = (miRead.Equals("Kludge"));    // so JIT won't know if true or false
                Console.WriteLine("'x' to quit, SPACE for Inline, nothing for Call, then ENTER: ");
                string way = Console.ReadLine();
                way = way.ToLower();
                if (way.Equals(" "))
                { LoopMessagesCall(); }
                else if (way.Equals("x"))
                { return; }
                else
                { LoopMessagesInline(); }

            } while (true);
        }
    }
}
```

Calls to LoopMessageInline() take about 7-8 milliseconds. Calls to LoopMessageCall() take less than 1 millisecond.

As mentioned above, neither MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining, nor using Delegates seems to help with this.

Comment: ".. I think the strings are always getting evaluated..." - what exactly do you mean by *string evaluation*?

Comment: Also, using `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` is not the most reliable profiling method. Have you tried profiling the application using other techniques availaible in Visual Studio, etc.? Described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/?view=vs-2022

Comment: If you worry about performance you should avoid `dynamic`.

Comment: Also sharing a full [mre] would be great.

Comment: Was afraid it would be too much code to post, but I'll try to make a minimal repro case.

Comment: Side note: you should make sure you understand where entertainment (invent custom logging framework) should stop and real work (using existing well proven logging framework) start. This is not to dissuade you from investing/optimizing your code but rather to make sure you stop at the right time *for you* - cost of optimizing goes significantly up with each obtained percentage of the change, and learning potential decreases in opposite direction.

Comment: I'm actually just wrapping a provided logging mechanism, so not reinventing too much I hope.  For the optimization, I'm trying to knock off an extra 5 milliseconds so that a pause in speech recognition is less perceptible.  Not essential, but great if I can make it work.

Comment: Edited the question to have a minimal repro case as a simple console app.

Comment: You have to use a delegate so you can delay the execution of the formatting statement.  Like  `public static void MenuWrite(Func<string> dlg { if (MenuItems) Console.Write(dlg); }`.  Easiest to call it with a lambda like `Logger.MenuWrite(() => $"Counting Down to the time {sw.Elapsed}");`.  That made the call flavor 25 times faster, improving it from x100 slower to about x4 slower than the explicit inline flavor.

Comment: Thanks @hanspassant, that did it!  You had one small typo, with a missing closing parenthesis on (Func<string> dlg), but fixed that up and this is *much* better.   I'll mark this as solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all use proper benchmarking tools - like [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet).

I have come up with the following benchmark:

```cs
namespace CS_Console_Test_05
{
    static public class Logger
    {
        public static bool MenuItems = false;

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static void MenuWrite(string msg)
        {
            if (MenuItems)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(msg);
            }
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static void MenuWriteFormattableString(FormattableString msg)
        {
            if (MenuItems)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(msg);
            }
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static void MenuWriteFunc(Func<string> msg)
        {
            if (MenuItems)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(msg());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class LoggerWrapperBench
{
    public static string Value = "TestVal";
    private const int Iterations = 1000;

    [Benchmark]
    public void LoopMessagesInline()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
        {
            if (Logger.MenuItems)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Counting Down to the time {Value}");
            }
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void LoopMessagesInlineFormatableString()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
        {
            Logger.MenuWriteFormattableString($"Counting Down to the time {Value}");
        }
    }
    
    [Benchmark]
    public void LoopMessagesInlineFunc()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
        {
            Logger.MenuWriteFunc(() => $"Counting Down to the time {Value}");
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void LoopMessagesCall()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
        {
            Logger.MenuWrite($"Counting Down to the time {Value}");
        }
    }
}
```

Which gives on my machine:

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen0 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LoopMessagesInline | 524.7 ns | 10.10 ns | 10.37 ns | - | - |
| LoopMessagesInlineFormatableString | 10,908.3 ns | 215.37 ns | 328.89 ns | 10.1929 | 64000 B |
| LoopMessagesInlineFunc | 1,031.8 ns | 18.34 ns | 21.12 ns | - | - |
| LoopMessagesCall | 14,523.6 ns | 286.28 ns | 391.86 ns | 14.0228 | 88000 B |

Making the lazy func approach closest to the inline one (though I wonder a bit why it does not allocate anything).

Note that inlining does not have much effect on string evaluation in case of `MenuWrite` and `MenuWriteFormattableString` because:

```cs
var s = DoSomething(); // like build string
if(...)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

And

```cs
if(...)
{
    Console.WriteLine(DoSomething());
}
```

Are not functionally equivalent in general case (due to possible side effects of the function call), so inlining should not change correctness of the program, so the string formatting gets called (at least it's my theory on the subject).

**UPD**

There is one more approach worth mentioning (though I was not able to make it perform faster and it can even preform even slower in case of multiple interpolated elements) - since .NET 6 you can create a [custom interpolated string handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/interpolated-string-handler):

```cs
[InterpolatedStringHandler]
public readonly ref struct LogInterpolatedStringHandler
{
    readonly StringBuilder? _builder;

    public LogInterpolatedStringHandler(int literalLength, int formattedCount)
    {
        if (Logger.MenuItems)
        {
            _builder = new StringBuilder(literalLength);
        }
    }

    public void AppendLiteral(string s) => _builder?.Append(s);

    public void AppendFormatted<T>(T t) => _builder?.Append(t?.ToString());

    internal string GetFormattedText()
    {
        if (_builder is not null)
        {
            var format = _builder.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(format);
            return format;
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

And usage:

```cs
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
public static void MenuWriteInterpolatedStringHandler(ref LogInterpolatedStringHandler msg)
{
    if(MenuItems) msg.GetFormattedText();
}
```

```
[Benchmark]
public void LoopMenuWriteInterpolatedStringHandler()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
    {
        Logger.MenuWriteInterpolatedStringHandler($"Counting Down to the time {Value}");
    }
}
```

Which gives on my machine:

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LoopMenuWriteInterpolatedStringHandler | 1,690.0 ns | 32.63 ns | 36.27 ns | - |
| LoopMessagesInline | 534.2 ns | 10.39 ns | 15.22 ns | - |

Comment: Thanks for the benchmark link.  Will be using that.  Should the `LoopMessagesInlineFormatableString()` call an have an `if (Logger.MenuItems)`, though?  Looks like this still shows a measurable benefit from avoiding creating/evaluating the string.

Comment: @tanr see the update. Also note that `Func` approach in case of local variables will lead to closures which will result in allocations.

Comment: @tanr _"Should the LoopMessagesInlineFormatableString() call an have an if (Logger.MenuItems), though?"_ - why? the predicate check is happening inside of `MenuWriteFormattableString`, is not it the whole idea of the method.

Comment: just thought `LoopMessagesInlineFormatableString` was trying to avoid creating the fully formatted string if `Logger.MenuItems == false`. All makes sense still.  Hadn't thought through the Func approach causing allocations. That could get expensive - though I think most such allocation would be short lived as I have no long running methods.

Comment: _"I think most such allocation would be short lived as I have no long running methods."_ -  yes, as the ones created as result of string formatting (though these ones can be bigger).

Answer (score 2):

Per @HansPassant comment, was able to avoid the perf hit by changing the method in the Logger class to:

```
public static void MenuWrite(Func<string> msg) 
{ 
    if (MenuItems) Console.Write(msg()); 
}
```

and changing the calls to it to be:

`Logger.MenuWrite(() => $"Counting Down to the time {sw.Elapsed}");`

The evaluation of sw.Elapsed is just for the repro case, of course. Time to do more reading on delegates - gotta remember this isn't C++.

EDIT: Per @GuruStron had to change `ConsoleWrite(msg)` to `ConsoleWrite(msg())`

Perf tests were very basic, using the Stopwatch in the minimal repro project listed in the question.

Comment: How did you measure that this avoided the perf hit?

Comment: Can you provide two examples showing the hit and the solution avoiding the hit?

Comment: Also, this doesn't action write the string in the `Func<string> msg` to the console. Did you test before posting?

Comment: `Console.Write(msg)` -> `Console.Write(msg())`.

Comment: @Enigmativity, edited the answer to include Guru Stron's correction.  I should have tested the actual output before posting - was just looking at the timings.  For an example of the perf hit, see the minimal repro project in my question.  For avoiding the hit, change that minimal repro to use the methods as listed above.